# Shorter way to instantiate and initialize an object of a base class with derived classes

Tags: c#, casting, initialization, instantiation

I have a pointer to a base class (`B`) and want to instantiate and initialize it with different derived classes based on a condition.

I look for a better and shorter solution for the following scenario. As you note on each case of the switch I should cast the pointer to a derived class to be able to initialize it. Is it possible that I do the instantiating, casting and initializing in more compact way?

```
BaseClass b;
switch (x)
{
   case 1:
       b = new D1(); // D1 is derived from BaseClass
       D1 d1 = (D1) b;
       d1.x = 1; // x is specific to D1 class
   break;
   case 2:
       b = new D2(); // D2 is derived from BaseClass
       D2 d2 = (D2) b;
       d2.y = 1; // y is specific to D2 class
   break;
}
b.z = 1;   // z is a common attribute
b.w = 2;   // w is a common attribute
BaseClassList.Add(b);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [object initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx):

```
switch (x)
{
   case 1:
       b = new D1 { x = 1 };
   break;
   case 2:
       b = new D2 { y = 1 };
   break;
}
```